# Two panels using same height display differently

Tags: java, macos, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm trying to make a full-screen `GUI` using Java which, on the `JFrame`, has 2 `JPanel`'s, one of which only takes roughly 0.10 of the screen width. When I place these panels on the frame, using the same height, they appear to display with a different height on Linux & Mac OS but they appear okay on Windows. Does anybody have any idea on how to make both panels the same height for Linux & Mac OS? I re-made the problem quickly using `WindowBuilder` for posting here.

```
package View;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import controller.ExitActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class TestFrame2 {

    private JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TestFrame2 window = new TestFrame2();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public TestFrame2() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        GraphicsDevice device = frame.getGraphicsConfiguration().getDevice();
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setSize((int)(frame.getWidth()*0.1), frame.getHeight());
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setBackground(Color.RED);
        panel1.setSize(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel1);

        // temporary close button
        ActionListener exitActionListener = new ExitActionListener();
        JButton exit = new JButton("Exit System");
        exit.setBounds(150 ,200, 150, 100);
        exit.addActionListener(exitActionListener);
        panel1.add(exit);

        //Set program as full screen
        device.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post a screenshot how it appears on Linux / Mac OS? Btw, I would try overriding the `getPreferredSize()` method of the panel instead of `setSize()` and adding it to `BorderLayout.LINE_START` / `BorderLayout.WEST`. And your setBounds call won't do much because panel1 has a (`Flow`)layout. (which is perfectly fine, maybe a `FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT))` would achieve what you want for the button's position)

Comment: @LuxxMiner Here's a screenshot of how it appears on Mac OS: http://imgur.com/zsfYG8m. Have tried messing around with getPreferredSize() and BorderLayout's however this resulted in the black panel stretching across the bottom of the screen instead. Also, I meant to mention the plan is for both panels to use GridBagLayout once they display properly and the button's position is irrelevant, it's only there for escaping full screen.

Comment: Where did you add the panel to? Probably `BorderLayout.SOUTH` or `BorderLayout.PAGE_END`? I've used `BorderLayout` with your code and it worked perfectly for me with `BorderLayout.LINE_START`.

Comment: @LuxxMiner Yep, my bad! Added to PAGE_END but changed it to LINE_START now and it appears to be working, thank you a lot!